# TensorFlow Keras 'accuracy' metric under the hood implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras

When building a classifier using TensorFlow Keras, one often monitors model accuracy by specifying `metrics=['accuracy']` during the compilation step:

```py
model = tf.keras.Model(...)
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=..., metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This behaves correctly whether or not the model outputs logits or class probabilities, and whether or not the model expects ground truth labels to be one-hot-encoded vectors or integer indices (i.e., integers in the interval `[0, n_classes)`).

This is not the case if one wants to use cross-entropy loss: each of the four combinations of the cases mentioned above requires a different `loss` value to be passed during the compilation step:

1. If the model outputs probabilities and the ground truth labels are one-hot-encoded, then `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` works.
2. If the model outputs probabilities and the ground truth labels are integer indices, then `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` works.
3. If the model outputs logits and the ground truth labels are one-hot-encoded, then `loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` works.
4. If the model outputs logits and the ground truth labels are integer indices, then `loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` works.

It seems that just specifying `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` is not robust enough to handle these four cases, whereas specifying `metrics=['accuracy']` *is* robust enough.

---

**Question**
What is happening behind the scenes when the user specifies `metrics=['accuracy']` in the model compilation step that allows the accuracy computation to be performed correctly regardless of whether the model outputs logits or probabilities and whether the ground truth labels are one-hot-encoded vectors or integer indices?

---

I suspect that the logits versus probabilities case is simple since the predicted class can be obtained as an argmax either way, but I would ideally like to be pointed to where in the TensorFlow 2 source code the computation is actually done.

Please note that I am currently using [TensorFlow 2.0.0-rc1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.0rc1/).

---

**Edit**
In pure Keras, `metrics=['accuracy']` is handled explicitly in the [`Model.compile` method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8b226f26b35348d934edb1213061993e7e5a1fa/keras/engine/training.py#L651-L665).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it: this is handled in [`tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training_utils.get_metric_function`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41474120daa68791e09eae99c8bdd8df093eda31/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L1007-L1046). In particular, the output shape is inspected to determine which accuracy function to use.

To elaborate, in the current implementation [`Model.compile`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41474120daa68791e09eae99c8bdd8df093eda31/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L184-L400) either delegates metric processing to [`Model._compile_eagerly`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41474120daa68791e09eae99c8bdd8df093eda31/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1563-L1575) (if executing eagerly) or does it directly. In either case, [`Model._cache_output_metric_attributes`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41474120daa68791e09eae99c8bdd8df093eda31/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1892-L1908) is called, which calls [`collect_per_output_metric_info`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41474120daa68791e09eae99c8bdd8df093eda31/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L748-L824) for both the unweighted and weighted metrics. This function loops over the provided metrics, calling `get_metric_function` on each one.